# How can I do to access to Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-8

Hello I setted up Gitlab on my raspberry but I can't access to the web page of gitlab. So i would like to know where is the *.html ? I tried to find in var/www/html but I see nothing... I precise I setted up apache on my raspberry. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

See [GitLab's guide to installation on the Raspberry Pi](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/04/21/gitlab-on-raspberry-pi-2/).

> Download the Omnibus package for Raspberry Pi 2 and install it:
>
> `wget https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads-packages/raspberry-pi/gitlab_7.9.0-omnibus.pi-1_armhf.deb`
>
> `sudo dpkg -i gitlab_7.9.0-omnibus.pi-1_armhf.deb`
>
> `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
>
> Sign in on your new micro-instance with username `root` and password `5iveL!fe`.

Comment: Yeah but how can I go to the index.html of gitlab ? Because I also have some other web pages (MySQL databse, owncloud...)

Comment: I don't understand your question. The traditional way to go to the index page of a website is using your web browser. If you are headless and don't have a web browser then you could try something like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/716180/how-to-access-web-page-via-terminal). If this doesn't answer your question then you might consider rewording it.